# how do i get this object to setText in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, settext

So, I've been making this BankPanel class to go with two other classes my teacher gave us for my Java course. I'm supposed to create a bank account object, and i need to get the variable values from the object to accountNameTF, accountnumberTf, and accountBalanceTF. Please help??

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class BankPanel extends JPanel
{
    private int amount;
    private JLabel accountName;
    private JLabel accountNumber;
    private JLabel accountBalance;
    private JLabel accountStatus;
    private JLabel depwitAmount;
    private JTextField accountNameTF;
    private JTextField accountNumberTF;
    private JTextField accountBalanceTF;
    private JTextField accountStatusTF;
    private JTextField depwitAmountTF;
    private JButton depositButton;
    private JButton withdrawButton;
    private int acctNumber;
    private double balance;
    private String name;

    Object myAcct()  // Create bank Account object   
    {
        acctNumber = 128895;
        balance = 0.00;
        name = "Bart Simpson";


    }

    public BankPanel()
   {
      amount = 0;

        accountName = new JLabel ("Account name: ");
        accountNumber = new JLabel ("Account number: ");
        accountBalance = new JLabel ("Account balance: ");
        accountStatus = new JLabel ("Account status: ");
        depwitAmount = new JLabel ("Deposit/Withdraw amount: ");
        accountNameTF = new JTextField (15);
        accountNumberTF = new JTextField (10);
        accountBalanceTF = new JTextField (10);
        accountStatusTF = new JTextField (10);
        depwitAmountTF = new JTextField (10);
        depositButton = new JButton ("Deposit");
        withdrawButton = new JButton ("Withdraw");

        depositButton.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
        withdrawButton.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
        BankPanel obj = new BankPanel(); 

        add (accountName);
        add (accountNameTF);
        add (accountNumber);
        add (accountNumberTF);
        add (accountBalance);
        add (accountBalanceTF);
        add (accountStatus);
        add (accountStatusTF);
        add (depositButton);
        add (withdrawButton);
        add (depwitAmount);
        add (depwitAmountTF);


      setBackground(Color.cyan);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
      accountNameTF.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
      accountNumberTF.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
      accountBalanceTF.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
      accountStatusTF.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
      depwitAmountTF.setText(Integer.toString(amount));
      accountNameTF.setText(myAcct.getName());
      accountNumberTF.setText(Integer.toString ( myAcct.getAcctNumber() ) );
      accountBalanceTF.setText(Double.toString( myAcct.getAcctNumber() ) );

   }
```

This is the BankAccount class:

```
class BankAccount 
{

 private int acctNumber;
 private double balance;
 private String name;

 private static int acctCount= 0;  //not an instance variable, but a class variable (static)

/** constructs a bank account with zero balance, zero account number
 and name set to Unknown

*/

public BankAccount() {
     acctNumber = 0;
     balance = 0.0;
     name = "Unknown";

     acctCount++;
}

/*
  constructs a bank account with an account number, an  initial balance, and
  an owner!
 */

public BankAccount(int acctNo, double initBalance, String owner) {
    acctNumber = acctNo;
    balance = initBalance;
    name = owner;

    acctCount++;
}


 //all of the mutator methods - set

 public void setAcctNumber(int acct)
 {
        acctNumber = acct;
 }

public void setBalance(double amount)
 {
    balance = amount;
 }

 public void setName(String someName)
 {
    name = someName;
 }

//all of the accessor methods - get

public int getAcctNumber()
{
    return acctNumber;
 }

public double getBalance()
 {
 return balance;
}

public String getName()
 {
    return name;
}


public void deposit(double amount)
{
 balance = balance + amount;
}

public void withdraw(double amount) {
 balance = balance - amount;
}

 //overloaded method.  charges a fee!
 public void withdraw(double amount, double fee)
 {
        balance = balance - amount - fee;
 }

public String toString()
{
        return ("BankAccount : acctNumber "  + acctNumber +  " balance : "     + balance 
           + " name : " + name  );
}

//Class method to display our private static variable
public static int getAcctCount()
{
    return ( acctCount );
}

}// end of class definition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm supposed to create a bank account object*
means to create an object of bankaccount class like

```
BankAccount b=new BankAccount();
```

*i need to get the variable values from the object to accountNameTF, accountnumberTf, and accountBalanceTF.*

```
accountNameTF.setText(b.name);
```

**note** i assume that `name` is a variable in BankAccount class
Suppose if you have getter and setter in bankaccount class then you use this way

```
accountNameTF.setText(b.getName());
```

Comment: @BlakeWinters accepting answers is the stackoverflow way of saying thank you

Comment: pls do not use b.name! use a getter instead!

Comment: @PrR3 I dont know the getter method name,so i just gave an example

Comment: @PrR3 I used myAcct.name (my BankAccount class already has getters written in it)

Comment: @javaBeginner alright. just wanted to mention good programming style for a java beginner...

Comment: @PrR3 as you suggested I have included get method also

Comment: So my teacher made the BankAccount class for us. I thought it had getters, but im only seeing accessors and mutators. also, the GUI runs but it won't give me the right values in the textfields

Comment: @BlakeWinters this seems to be another question.So please post another another qustion showing bankaccount class and please specify exact problems.

Answer (score 0):

You just call `BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount(bankPanel);` when you have the constructor set up correctly:

```
public BankAccount(BankPanel bankPanel)
{
    this.whateverYouNeed = bankPanel.whateverYouNeed;
    // repeat for other variables
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this:

```
BankAccount ba = new BankAccount();
accountNameTF.setText(ba.getText());
accountnumberTf.setText(ba.getText());
accountBalanceTF.setText(ba.getText());
```

?

Comment: @PrR3 ba.getText() was an example, if you see -  code of BankAccount class is not presented!